How to redirect a callback directly to an app?
I'm working on an desktop app that uses GitHub OAuth, and it utilizes a flow of making a callback with authorization details, I need to redirect a callback directly to the .NET app (It'll be headless CLI tool as well as MAUI app, I would like to redirect to both, if possible)
I have seen a feature like that in other applications, when your browser prompts you to open an executable
Thank you <3
I have looked up things online, but had no luck finding something helpful

Using OAuth 2 with desktop c# Application
